# Random sample groups instead of rows in SQL

Tags: sql, group-by, amazon-athena, presto, sample

So let's say that my table is like this:

```
+---------------------+
|ColA   | ColB | ColC |
+---------------------+
| AA       C        5 |      
| AA       C        8 |     
| AA       C        9 |      
| BB       D        3 |      
| BB       D        4 |    
| CC       E        1 |    
| CC       E        2 |     
| CC       E        3 |     
| CC       E        5 |    
+---------------------+
```

I want to randomly sample groups from COL A instead of rows. Each group is a sequence of events and i want all those events for each group, so that's why i do not want to just sample rows. I would like to sample like this below:

```
+---------------------+
 ColA  | ColB |   ColC 
+---------------------+
| AA       C        5 |      
| AA       C        8 |     
| AA       C        9 |    
| CC       E        1 |      
| CC       E        2 |      
| CC       E        3 |     
| CC       E        5 |      
+---------------------+
```

The below obviously samples rows so it's not good.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE TABLE_SAMPLE BERNOULI(1)
GROUP BY COLUMN A
```

I also have a COL B with 10 groups and i would like all those qroups to have an equal representation in respect to their total number of rows. Thank you!

Comment: can you please add some sample data and desired output?

Answer (score 0):

There's no direct way of doing that in Presto / Trino. There are a couple of approaches you can take, though.

If you want deterministic sampling, you can convert the group to a number by applying a uniform hash function and selecting a percentage of the groups. For instance:

```
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE bitwise_and(from_big_endian_64(xxhash64(cast(a as varbinary))), 1023) <= 0.5 * 1023
```

It works by:

- Computing a hash of the grouping column with [`xxhash64`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/binary.html?#xxhash64): `xxhash64(cast(a as varbinary))`. That produces a 64-bit binary value.
- Convert the binary value to a number with [`from_big_endian_64`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/binary.html?#from_big_endian_64) and pick, say, 10 bits out of it using [`bitwise_and(x, 1023)`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/bitwise.html#bitwise_and). That produces a number between 0 and 1023.
- Sample at `1%` by selecting any groups such that the value above is less than 0.01 * 1023.

If you want non-deterministic random sampling of groups, you can first sample the groups and then select rows matching those groups:

```sql
WITH 
   groups AS (SELECT DISTINCT colA FROM t),
   sampled_groups AS (SELECT * FROM groups TABLESAMPLE BERNOULLI(1)),
SELECT * 
FROM t
WHERE colA IN (TABLE sampled_groups)
```