# sampling groups instead of rows

Tags: sql, random, pandas-groupby, amazon-athena, presto

I want to randomly select  based on group ids (ColA) instead of rows. Let's say my inital table is this:

```
+---------------------+
|ColA   | ColB | ColC |
+---------------------+
| AA       C        5 |      
| AA       C        8 |     
| AA       C        9 |      
| BB       D        3 |      
| BB       D        4 |    
| CC       E        1 |    
| CC       E        2 |     
| CC       E        3 |     
| CC       E        5 |    
+---------------------+
```

I want to get something like this:

```
+---------------------+
 ColA  | ColB |   ColC 
+---------------------+
| AA       C        5 |      
| AA       C        8 |     
| AA       C        9 |    
| CC       E        1 |      
| CC       E        2 |      
| CC       E        3 |     
| CC       E        5 |      
+---------------------+
```

So let's say i want to get whole groupings from Col A randomly. I have done this but it gives me random rows rather than groups

```
SELECT distinct  ColA,ColB, ColC FROM TABLE
ORDER BY  RAND()
LIMIT 20000
```

I'd appreciate any clues on how to implement it.

Comment: Please, clarify the rule. Your query will return all the possible `ColA` data in random order. It will not return a sample because to *restrict* the result set you need to specify some restriction via `where`, `having`, `join`. How to get only groups `AA` and `CC` in your "something like" result?

Comment: You have already asked [almost the same](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69617372/2501279) question. It is not very clear what are you trying to achieve here. From the provided example it looks like `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ColA  != 'BB'` should do the trick. Can you please explain a little bit more what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Random sample groups instead of rows in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69617372/random-sample-groups-instead-of-rows-in-sql)

Comment: No that will not do it cause that's just an example. I want just a sample of all the groups from Col A. I think my desired output is clear on what i want to achieve

Comment: @TBA no it doesn't

Comment: You SELECT 1 column, but want 3 columns to be returned?!?

Comment: @Unicorn07 I understand that it will not achieve your goal, but I'm not the only one experiencing confusion here so it is safe to assume that your evaluation of your desired output is not fully correct.

Comment: @Guru Stron So let's say that each unique id of ColA has a group of rows. I want  some of those whole groups across my entire dataset. Sorry i'm not sure how else to explain it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description you can use your single column query in subselect:

```
SELECT *
FROM dataset
WHERE ColA IN (
        SELECT *
        FROM (
                SELECT distinct ColA 
                FROM dataset
            )
        ORDER BY rand()
        LIMIT 2
    )
```